# Trying to write to a cell (Application defined or object defined error)

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
For Each cell In Worksheets("bulk & prod").Range("B4:M4")
    If StrComp(cell.Value, "#N/A") Then
        Windows("Analysis.xlsx").Activate
        Dim y As Workbook
        Set y = ActiveWorkbook


        y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:" & num).SetValue (wb.Name)

        num = num + 1

    End If
  Next cell
```

The idea is that I want to paste wb.Name to the cell, where num starts at one and increments, leading to a nice column of file names. 
I've only been using VBA for 3 days, and have hit a dead end, any help would be awesome.

Comment: have you set `wb.name` to be anything?

Comment: Also, just to save you a few lines and seconds, you could shorten        `Windows("Analysis.xlsx").Activate`
        `Dim y As Workbook`
        `Set y = ActiveWorkbook` to `Dim y as Workbook`
`Set y = Windows("Analysis.xlsx")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Num` is already set to a valid value, not 0, and `wb` refers to a valid object, you should remove the colon from the range address and there is no `SetValue` method for a range in VBA:

```
Range("A" & num).Value = wb.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things to notice..

1. A:x is not valid range (assuming num in your case is an integer and assigned non-zero value)
2. .SetValue is not a valid method, hence change it to

y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & num).value = (wb.Name)

3. Since it's string comparison, your If conditional may not work effectively unless you change it absolutely match something like  if(a = 0) do something.

remember, "If string1 is equal to string2, the StrComp function will return 0."

3. You don't need to activate the target workbook for each matched value, you may simply reference it without needing to activate it. This may actually fail if you are activating a new workbook which is opened in a new instance of Excel.
4. Remember, in excel #N/A without preceded by a single Quote (inside cell) is consider as reserver work NA and cannot be compared using StrComp method. Instead you may simply use ISNA() if you desired comparison is "#N/A". However it's not available in VBA, hence use alternative method.

Here is the simplified version. Let me know if it fails.

```
'== My assumptions ====
Dim wb As Workbook
'Set your current workbook; more ideally use Workbooks(<name>) instead.
Set wb = Workbooks(<source workbook name>)
num = 1
'======================

Dim y As Workbook
Set y = Workbooks(<target workbook name>)

For Each cell In wb.Worksheets("bulk & prod").Range("B4:M4")

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(cell.Value) Then

        y.Sheets(1).Range("A" & num) = (wb.Name)
        num = num + 1

    End If

Next cell
```